# How to configure smartparens for lisp mode?

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to configure smartparens in a way that it doesn't insert a second ' (single quote) if in lisp mode ?

Comment: Not a very clear description.

Comment: The problem is that ' is used to quote a list in lisp, so every time I have to quote a list, I have to delete the second '

Comment: Maybe give an example, showing "the second quote mark". I guess you are saying that if you type `'` then smart parens inserts `''` (?).

Comment: If you want to quote a list, you can select it then quote.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes.  Here's the easy way:

```
(require 'smartparens-config)
```

This [sets up smartparens with some default settings](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens#default-configuration), most of which I find either useful or inoffensive (take a look with `M-x find-library <RET> smartparens-config`).  One of them disables the single-quote pair in various Lisp modes.

That should take care of this pair almost everywhere it's going to be a problem.  The one place it seems to miss is the `eval-expression` (`M-:`) command, so I add this line:

```
(sp-local-pair 'minibuffer-inactive-mode "'" nil :actions nil)
```

This will affect all commands that use the minibuffer for input, so if you frequently use single quotes in the minibuffer for some reason, you may want to find a more narrowly-focused solution.

If you want to do more tweaking, [here](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Pair-management) is the relevant smartparens documentation.

Comment: For a more narrowly-focused solution, this is what I use to disable paired single-quote only in `eval-expression`:

    (sp-local-pair 'minibuffer-inactive-mode "'" nil
                   :actions nil
                   :unless '(my-in-eval-expression-p))
    (defun my-in-eval-expression-p (id action context)
      (equalp last-command 'eval-expression))